# Firebase - Firestore rules: throttle create requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Since I've found nothing online. I would like to know, if there is a firestore rule that allows create request for stories from a simple user only after every 60 sec?

My Data-structure is simple:

```
stories--
        |
        - document 1
        - document 2 
         ...
users--
       |
        - document 1
        - document 2
         ...
```

I basically have two top level collections. The documents of my Stories collection contains also a timestamp property.
So on the rules for my stories collection, it should look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /stories/{storyId} {

      allow create: if isSignedIn() && isVerified() && throttleRequestTime();
    }
  }
}

function throttleRequestTime() {
    return request.time < ***the value to compare*** + duration.value(60, 's');
}
```

Comment: What about https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.timestamp_ and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.duration_? (I've never tried so I cannot help you more but definitely curious to see if it can be use in your case!)

Comment: You can definitely protect access to each document with the `timestamp` property. You can however not protect querying across the collection based on the `timestamp` property (at least not when I last tried it).

Comment: Nevertheless thanks Frank, at least u did a good job at the this years Firebase summit ;D